# How to show only date in index view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

**In Model:**

```cs
public DateTime? FromDate { get;set; }
```

**In view:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="label other">
        From Date
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "Date", min = "1944-01-01", max = "2019-01-01" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

When we enter the date from the `DateTime` picker calendar it enter the date:

[image: When we enter the date from the DateTime picker calendar it enter the date]

In `Index` view it shows the time also:

[image: In Index view it shows the time also]

problem is that I do not want to show the time with the date in the Index view .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set display format for the `DateTime` property type use the [`DisplayFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute in the model declaration, like below:

```cs
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank my issue is solved